# (Solved) How to create an event receiver for RoleAssignments on file in sharepoint 2013

Tags: permissions, event-receivers

I'm trying for like 5 days to achieve this event and i got to this but still not even close to what i want. I need to change permissions on file added in library like: user which added file to have full right, his manager same, his department colleagues read rights and rest of people no right. With this part of code i achived to BreakInheritance on item and remove "Advanced" menu from Shared with, but i still can edit file properties. Any ideeas please? Hope that i managed to describe well what i need, if not please ask.

```
public override void ItemAdded(SPItemEventProperties properties)
    {
        base.ItemAdded(properties);
        if (properties.ListTitle.Equals("Documents"))
        {
            using (SPSite site = new SPSite(properties.WebUrl))
            {
                site.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
                {
                    SPUser user = web.CurrentUser;
                    SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                            SPListItem li = properties.ListItem;
                            SPFile lf = web.GetFile(li.Url);

                            SPRoleType read = SPRoleType.Guest;
                            lf.Item.BreakRoleInheritance(true);
                            while (lf.Item.RoleAssignments.Count > 0)
                            {
                                lf.Item.RoleAssignments.Remove(0);
                            }
                            AssignPermissionsToItem(lf.Item, user, read);
                            web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;

                        }

                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                        }

                    });
                }
            }
        }
    }

public static void AssignPermissionsToItem(SPListItem item, SPPrincipal obj, SPRoleType roleType)
{
    if (!item.HasUniqueRoleAssignments)
    {
        item.BreakRoleInheritance(true);
    }

    SPRoleAssignment roleAssignment = new SPRoleAssignment(obj);
    SPRoleDefinition roleDefinition = item.Web.RoleDefinitions.GetByType(roleType);
    roleAssignment.RoleDefinitionBindings.Add(roleDefinition);

    item.RoleAssignments.Add(roleAssignment);
}
```

Comment: It's better to put in your solution as an answer rather than editing the question; and then you can come back after 2 days and mark it as the answer.

Comment: I wanted to do that, but I'm new here and can't answer my question only after 10 hours. I'll it edit tomorrow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved myself. So here is code for adding Read permissions on item added for current user. Hope someone will find this helpfull. If any question, don't mind to ask.

```
public override void ItemUpdated(SPItemEventProperties properties)
{
    base.ItemUpdated(properties);
    if (properties.ListTitle.Equals("Documents"))
    {
        using (SPSite site = new SPSite(properties.WebUrl))
        {
            site.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
            using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
            {
                SPUser user = web.CurrentUser;
                SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
                {
                    try
                    {
                        web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                        SPListItem li = properties.ListItem;
                        SPFile lf = web.GetFile(li.Url);

                        SPRoleType read = SPRoleType.Reader;
                        li.BreakRoleInheritance(false);
                        while (li.RoleAssignments.Count > 0)
                        {
                            li.RoleAssignments.Remove(0);
                        }
                        AssignPermissionsToItem(li, user, read);
                        web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;

                    }
                    catch (Exception ex){   }
                });
            }
        }
    }
}

public static void AssignPermissionsToItem(SPListItem item, SPPrincipal obj, SPRoleType roleType)
{
    SPRoleAssignment roleAssignment = new SPRoleAssignment(obj);
    SPRoleDefinition roleDefinition = item.Web.RoleDefinitions.GetByType(roleType);
    roleAssignment.RoleDefinitionBindings.Add(roleDefinition);

    item.RoleAssignments.Add(roleAssignment);
    item.Update();
}
```

Comment: great, thanks for sharing.. saved me 5 days as well :)